# Как переделать переменную RaycastHit в GameObject

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пускаю лучь, получаю переменную RaycastHit hit. Теперь мне нужно узнать какой это обьект и записать его в переменную GameObject hittedObject. Но я не знаю как это сделать. У обоих переменных можно прописать hit.transfrom или hittedObject.transform. Подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее 
hit.collider.gameObject
Должно помочь

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Принять ответ смогу только через 12 минут, поэтому подожду. Но сработало :)

Comment: Вы так же можете получить gameObject c hit.trsnsform.gameObject

Comment: Вообще интельсенс очень помогает в подобных случаях. Достаточно просто просмотреть все что он выдает.